# Need to add two objects together in Java that consist of Feet & Inches

Tags: java, object

I have an issue that I can't quite wrap my mind around. Maybe someone could help me out.

I have created a DISTANCE class that contains two variables FEET & INCHES.  I need to add a Method to that class that adds two separate DISTANCE objects of Feet & Inches.

Here is my class so far:

```
public class Distance {

    static int feet; // 0 - infinity
    static int inches; // 0 - infinity

    public Distance() { // default constructor

        this.feet = 0;
        this.inches = 0;
    }

    public Distance(int ft, int in){ // parametarized constructor

        this.feet = ft;
        this.inches = in;

        System.out.println("constructor w/2 ints : " + feet + ", " + inches);
    }

    public void setDistance(int ft, int in){

        setFeet( ft );
        setInches( in );    
    }

    public static int getFeet() {

        return (feet);
    }

    public static void setFeet(int feet) {
        Distance.feet = feet;
    }

    public static int getInches() {
        return inches;
    }

    public static void setInches( int inches) {
        Distance.inches = inches;

    }



    public Distance(Distance d){

        //Distance total = d;

        d.getDistance();

    }

    private int getDistance() {
        int totalInches;

        totalInches = (feet * 12) + inches;

        return totalInches;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + feet;
        result = prime * result + inches;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Distance other = (Distance) obj;
        if (feet != other.feet)
            return false;
        if (inches != other.inches)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Distance [feet=" + feet + ", inches=" + inches + "]";
    }


}
```

The method I am trying to write needs to add to Distance Objects. Here is what I've tried so far: if

public Distance add(Distance d){

```
    Distance total;

    total = this.getDistance() + d.getDistance();

    return total;

}
```

Comment: ok and what goes wrong with it?

Comment: I'd recommend to use just inches internally.

Comment: Perform the arithmetic in inches, and then convert back to feet and inches.

Comment: The use of `static` members for `feet` and `inches` is 100% incorrect.  These members must not be `static`.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I was just not breaking the object up into it's variables. I also see the issue with static variables too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to assign an `int` to a `Distance` object, use your constructor

```
public Distance add(Distance d){
    Distance total = new Distance(this.feet + d.feet, this.inches + d.inches);
    return total;
}
```

Also, you should probably not declare feet and inches as static variables since whenever you modify it, it changes for **all** of your Distance objects.
Change from:

```
static int feet; // 0 - infinity
static int inches; // 0 - infinity
```

to:

```
private int feet; // 0 - infinity
private int inches; // 0 - infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using static variable in the object.  Each time you instantiate a Distance object you set all Distance objects to those values.

Distance a = new Distance(1,3);
Distance b = new Distance(3,1);

System.out.println(a.getFeet());
//should return 3

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your code

```
public static Distance add(Distance d1,Distance d2){
    return new Distance(d1.getFeet() + d2.getFeet(), d1.getInches() + d2.getInces);
}
```

Your entire code should be changed to the following

```
public class Distance {

    private int feet;
    private int inches;

    public Distance(int ft, int in){ // parametarized constructor
        this.feet = ft;
        this.inches = in;
        System.out.println("constructor w/2 ints : " + feet + ", " + inches);
    }

    public int getFeet() {

        return feet;
    }

    public int getInches() {
        return inches;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return (feet * 12) + inches;
    }

    public static Distance add(Distance d1,Distance d2){
        return new Distance(d1.getFeet() + d2.getFeet(), d1.getInches() + d2.getInces);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + feet;
        result = prime * result + inches;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Distance other = (Distance) obj;
        if (feet != other.getFeet())
            return false;
        if (inches != other.getInches())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Distance [feet=" + getFeet() + ", inches=" + getInches() + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

```
public class Distance {

    private int feet;
    private int inches;

    public Distance(int feet, int inches) {
        this.feet = feet;
        this.inches = inches;
    }

    public int getDistanceInInches() {
        return feet * 12 + inches;
    }

    public Distance add(Distance distance) {
        return new Distance(this.feet + distance.feet, this.inches  + distance.inches);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Distance [feet=" + feet + ", inches=" + inches + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note by mutating the calling object you are destroying the value in it. The question say to add 2 object and put it in the 3 object...